# What is the equivalent of Array.Sort(array, array) in a PCL

Tags: c#, arrays, xamarin

I am trying to sort two arrays (typically keys & values) in an optimal manner. In standard C#, the method Array.Sort(Array, Array) works well for it, however, there is no such method.

More explicitly, this code is possible in standard C# but not within a cross platform PCL build:

```
        double[] keys = new double[100];
        object[] values = new object[100];
        Array.Sort(keys, values);
```

Is there any such method available or do I have to use and instantiate an anonymous type like this?

```
        double[] keys = new double[100];
        object[] values = new object[100];
        var list = Enumerable.Range(0, keys.Length).Select(i => new { Val = keys[i], Obj = values[i] }).ToList();
        list.Sort((v1, v2) => v1.Val.CompareTo(v2.Val));
        for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
        {
            values[i] = list[i].Obj;
            keys[i] = list[i].Val;
        }
```

EDIT: Some people say that I should see the function, however, I am using this:

```
    #region Assembly System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
    // C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile259\System.Runtime.dll
    #endregion
```

And all I see is[image: No array sort]

Comment: even if you use plc, you need to be able to use  Array.Sort(keys, values);. it is exist on Using System name space

Comment: Have you looked into your .NET Prtable profile? Maybe its too restricted for what you actually need and removes the method from your PCL

Comment: If possible I would recommend not doing PCL for any new development. Switch over to a .NET Core library [targeting the profile to match what you need for your PCL compatability](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html)

Comment: @Thomas I see all on : #region Assembly mscorlib, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e

Comment: @thomas what approach did you finally go with to get the array sorting in your PCL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are able to use `Array.Sort()`, Even if you are using **PLC** Project, just ensure you add the following :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

Comment: This does not work. As per https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85y6y2d3(v=vs.110).aspx#Version Information, this sort method is not available in portable class libraries. Is there some equivalent that can be used in PCL's?

Comment: I don't know why this answer is accepted, this particular overload of Array.Sort (taking 2 arrays) is not available in a PCL project.